# Generating a button on php checkbox selection from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this project where the user selects items using a checkbox and then a button is generated from that item's name.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>webs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Select User:</h2>
    <div>
    <form method="POST">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <th></th>
            <th>Subject</th>

        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php
            include('get.php');
                $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `subjects`");
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
             ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['subject']; ?>" name="id[]"></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Subjects selected:</h2>
    <button class="button"><span><?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id):

            $sq=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `subjects` where subject='$id'");
            $srow=mysqli_fetch_array($sq);
            echo $srow['subject']."<br>";
            endforeach;

        }

    ?></span></button>

</div>
```

I did make a button but the output was just one big button formed from all selections.

[image]

How do I make buttons individually per item? Thanks.
Also, additionally, how can I make this dynamic? no need for a "Submit" button?

Comment: `<button class="button">` should be inside your `foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id):` if you need separate button per `id`.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what problem you're having.  You don't seem to have _attempted_ to create a button element per results.  You're already doing a `foreach` loop.  So just create the button _inside_ the loop instead of outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should try Following code For generate Separate Button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>webs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Select User:</h2>
    <div>
    <form method="POST">
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <th></th>
            <th>Subject</th>

        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php
            include('get.php');
                $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `subjects`");
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
             ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['subject']; ?>" name="id[]"></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<div>
    <h2>Subjects selected:</h2>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
            foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id):
                $sq=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `subjects` where subject='$id'");
                $srow=mysqli_fetch_array($sq);
    ?>
            <button class="button">
                 <span> 
                    <?php echo $srow['subject']; ?> 
                 </span> 
            </button>
            <?php
              endforeach;
              }
            ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But no text is appearing inside the buttons.

Comment: I Have updated a code little bit. Please re-copy and paste it. remain to print inside button. so I have put echo for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will use JavaScript for this I'm giving you syntax in JavaScript, because JavaScript is the best way to make it dynamic.

**First arrange PHP code**

```
include 'get.php';

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select *  from `subjects`");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $subject = $row['subject'];
    echo "<tr>
        <td><input type='checkbox' onclick='validate()' value='".$subject."' name='id[]' id='myCheck'></td>
            <td> ".$subject."</td>
        </tr>"; 
    ?>
```

**Then JavaScript**

```
function validate() {
    var check = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;
    var val = document.getElementById("myCheck").value;
    document.getElementById("myCheck").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("myBtn").value = val;
}
```

**Button**

```
<button class="button animate" id="myBtn">
```

**Adding animation to button**

```
.animate {
  -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
  animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
  from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
  to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes animatezoom {
  from {transform: scale(0)}
  to {transform: scale(1)}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `<button class="button">` inside foreach,  mitkosoft thats right.